# "If I had known" structure

Tags: tense, irrealis-mood

There's a video that the person says:

> If I'd known meeting you **would have led** me here...`

My question is that the last part of the sentence seems wrong to me. Isn't it supposed to be *If I'd known meeting you **would lead** me here...*?

I'm guessing that it was to say that if I knew meeting you would lead me here, I wouldn't meet you so the sentence of mine seems correct to me.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes, your version makes perfect sense. Even native speakers sometimes get their tenses mixed up.

Comment: [This from wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/if-id-have-known.1381035/) might be useful: *in AmE "If I'd have known", the "I'd" stands for "I would". "If I'd have known" can also be heard in BrE, but there the "I'd" stands for "I had", **at least among older speakers**. This is evident from the fact that older speakers over here occasionally use the inverted version "**Had he have known**".* I'm one of those "older speakers", and to my ear the non-contracted AmE version *If I **would have known...*** just sounds really weird (for me it's *If I **had** have known...).*

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is about "if I'd known", not "if I'd have known" (which I think is nonstandard). The grammar of "if I had known (that) meeting you would have led me here" / "... would lead me here" seems to me to be an unrelated issue.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thanks for your answer. Understandable, thanks for that. So, just for reassurance, let me right it this way:
If I had know (that [Is it okay to use it and sometimes not use that?]) meeting you (?) me here, I wouldn't have met you. Instead of (?), `would lead` makes sense and `would've led` doesn't make sense, correct?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for that but no. It's not about the usage of it, it's about the intermediary sentence's structure.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I was thinking that maybe both are correct? I think that using `would lead` means that the person is talking about the thing he/she's been led to right now but `would have led` is referring to the thing he/she has or had been led to in past and is talking about it right now? But based on the video, because he's talking about the thing he's been led to by his friend at the time, he should've used `would lead` but if he was talking about e.g. something he had been led to by his friend in past and has now found out that it's been bad, he should've said `would have led`?

Comment: I find your reasoning rather confusing! In the hypothetical past, the speaker might have said "I know that meeting [that person] will lead me [to that place]." So the sentence in the conditional is "If I had known [that] meeting you would lead me here..."

Comment: @KateBunting: OR (primarily AmE) *If I **would have known** [that] meeting you would lead me here...*, OR (sometimes, BrE) *If I **had have known** [that] meeting you would lead me here...* But anyone might continue with ***...would have led** me here...*, and I can't see that unnecessarily repeating the Perfect form would have any semantic implications.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Understood! Thank you for your time.